# Relation between loss function and the target function ?

Tags: functions, optimization, machine-learning

I would like to know how to prove that the minimizer of some loss function is equivalent to calculating some properties of the target function?
For example:

**Regression Loss :**

**Square loss**: $$ f_p(x)= \int_Y ydp(y|x)$$

**Absolute loss**  $$f_(p)=median ~~~p(y|x)$$ where 
$$median~~ p(.)= y  ~~~~~~~s.t. ~~~~ \int_{-\infty}^y tdp(t)= \int_y^{+\infty} tdp(t).$$

**Classification Loss :**
**Hinge-loss**
 $$ f_p(x)=sign(p(1|x)-p(-1|x))$$

**Logistic loss**
$$ f_p(x)= \log \frac{ p(1|x)}{p(-1|x)} $$

Comment: Sorry for not understanding, but what exactly are you asking?